# Delete sms in broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to delete a `SMS` after receiving in broadcast receiver. I read other posts they said we can do it with `abortBroadcast();` but it doesn't work for me.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//###
Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage message =SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
//###
                Num = message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                Matn = message.getDisplayMessageBody();
//###
                for (int i = 0 ; i < myDbHelper.getBlockNumber().size() ; i++) {
                    //###

                    String a1 = myDbHelper.getBlockNumber().get(i);
                    String a2 = "98"+myDbHelper.getBlockNumber().get(i);
                    String a3 = "+98"+myDbHelper.getBlockNumber().get(i);
                    String a4 = "0098"+myDbHelper.getBlockNumber().get(i);
                    String a5 = "0"+myDbHelper.getBlockNumber().get(i);
                    String a6 = myDbHelper.getBlockName().get(i);
                    String b = myDbHelper.getBlockNumber().get(i).substring(1,myDbHelper.getBlockNumber().get(i).length());
                    String b1 = "98"+b;
                    String b2 = "+98"+b;
                    String b3 = "0098"+b;
                    String b4 = "0"+b;
//###
                    if (Num.equals(a1)||Num.equals(a2)||Num.equals(a3)||Num.equals(a4)||Num.equals(a5)||Num.equals(a6)||Num.equals(b)||Num.equals(b1)||Num.equals(b2)||Num.equals(b3)||Num.equals(b4)){
                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"it's Block",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }

                }
//###
}
```

I wrote `abortBroadcast();` in places where i spicified with `//###` but it doesn't work. and it's
Android Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiverBlock"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999999999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

At first when a `sms` was received it showed a toast (in my codes). and now when I set my app as default `sms` app but it doesn't show any toast. it means it can't read my receiver.

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: `abortBroadcast()` hasn't worked for the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast since KitKat, and it wasn't very reliable before that.

Comment: abortbroadcast() doesn't work for 4.4 and above or 44 and below or just 4.4?

Comment: `abortBroadcast()` on the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast does not work at all for versions >= 4.4 (API level 19, KitKat).

Comment: But I tested on android 6 (API23) and didn't work.

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't. Please reread my comments carefully. I'm not sure how else to put it.  It will not work on 4.4, 5.*, 6.*, 7.*, etc.

Comment: Please see edited post, 2 latest lines